# How to jump to the beginning of the code?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am making a program that asks a user to put a input. If the user puts in the input it will show is input and then finish the program. How do I make the program start from the beginning?
my code is built like this: (just showing the build not the code itself)

```
please enter user input:
while (x != y)
{ 
    if ( x == y )
    { 
        printf("printing something");
    }
    else if (x > y )
    {
        printf("printing something");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("printing something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the input inside a while loop

Comment: Cant since the x is num(the input), and num is only defined after the while loop

Comment: So add another while loop around it all

Comment: That will say what? while(true)? tried that already.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(void)
{
    int num = 0;
    while( 1 )
    {
        printf("This is a game to find the password. Start this game by trying to guess it with numbers from 1 - 100. The program will tell you if you are close or not.\n");

        num = 0; // reset the num back to zero
        while (num != 65)
        {
            printf("please enter a number:\n");
            num = GetInt();

            if (num == 65)
            {
                printf("Nice!!\n");
                break; // exit the while (num != 65)
            }
            else if (num > 50 && num < 60 )
            {
                printf("almost there! go higher!\n");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: causes an infinity loop.

Comment: well yeah. You need someway of breaking out of the loop. You need a condition that once it'e met it will break out of the loop.

Comment: What happens is that it will print out what I want it to but it will not go to the start of the program...

Comment: The start of your program meaning where ??? just before the while loop ?

Comment: here is the code: ignore the input types. they were modified. http://pastebin.com/iE8W9UnJ

Comment: causes infinity loop :(

Comment: I know I told you that. You only want it to go back to the start program once ??

Comment: after every time the user inputs a number.

Comment: you want it to say this after every time you get an input ??`printf("This is a game to find the password.....`

Comment: no just the "please enter a number". I tried to do this with the "return" command.

Comment: The code I posted should do just that. unless it goes into a case that has a `break` statement then it will exit the `while (num != 65)`

Comment: it still causes an infinity loop...

Comment: What do you mean by  `infinity loop`  ??

Comment: It wont stop writing the message in the else if's. This is my updated code: http://pastebin.com/iEVvQfGL

Comment: `while ( num != 65 ) { if ( num == 65 ) ...` is probably not what you want, and neither is `if (num > 60 && num < 50)`.

Comment: Thats not my code. my code is: if (num > 50 && num < 60). and why would I not want the while loop code?

Comment: @user2634624: It's the code you pasted. If the code you pasted is not the code you're actually using, then you're wasting everyone's time. As for the `while` loop code, there's no point having an `if` statement which your `while` loop prevents from ever being true.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using `goto`:

```
HERE: please enter user input:
while (x!= y)
{ 
    if ( x == y )
    { 
        printf("printing something");
    }
    else if (x > y )
    {
        printf("printing something");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("printing something");
    }
    goto HERE;
}
```

In this example however as you can see you you never break while. You have to use
`goto` carefully.

Edit:

The above code has a mistake. In order to get inside the `while` loop `x!=y`. But then
you check `x==y` which is always `false`. So:

```
HERE: please enter user input:  
while (true)
{ 
    if ( x == y )
    { 
        printf("printing something");
        break;
    }
    else if (x > y )
    {
        printf("printing something");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("printing something");
    }
    goto HERE;
}
```

Edit 2:

You have only **ONE** while loop

```
int num;

//your code here

HERE:
num = GetInt();
while(true)
{
   if (num == 65)
   {
       printf("Nice!!\n");
       break;
   }
   else if (num > 50 && num < 60 )

   }
   else if (something )
       something
   }
   .
   .
   .
   else{
       something
   }
   goto HERE;
}
```

valter

Comment: returns an infinity loop :(

Comment: When do you want your program to finish?

Comment: when the user inputs the correct number. see the full code: http://pastebin.com/iE8W9UnJ (dont pay attention to the input types, they were modified.)

Comment: I tried...it did not work like that either. look at my full code.http://pastebin.com/ZLGrAMGQ