# Guess the number game missing a loop

Tags: c, cs50

I was trying to do a "Guess the number" game that would use a verification to see if the number is low, high or equal to the random number. I want to do a loop verification that will say if the number is to high and to try again!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int skittles = rand() % 1024;
    printf("%d\n", skittles);
    printf("choose a number betwen 1 to 1024\n");



    int numpessoa = GetInt();

    printf("%d\n", numpessoa);

if (numpessoa < skittles)
{
    printf("numpessoa < skittles");
    numpessoa = GetInt();
}

if (numpessoa > skittles)
{
    printf("numpessoa > skittles");
    numpessoa = GetInt();
}

if (numpessoa == skittles)
{
    printf("numpessoa == skittles");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you don't have a loop in your code.

Comment: It would be helpful to add what part of this you are struggling with conceptually.  Narrow it down a bit... unxnut has a good point to start.

Comment: There is a similar question. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291323/how-to-jump-to-the-beginning-of-the-code">how-to-jump-to-the-beginning-of-the-code>

Answer (score 2):

If this is an homework,you shouldn't ask its solution directly.
I only can provide some pseudocode.

```
loop forever 
    get user's guess
    check guess against answer
        guess differs answer ,then provide some hints 
        guess equals answer,tell user he/she is right and break out of this loop
```

And there is an another bug in your code.
The 1024 modulo of an random integer is between 0 and 1023.